# I am unable to load django static files from css in html

Tags: html, django, django-urls

I am unable to load static files from inline-css in html file, which is present in the templates file in the django app.
For reference, the original file code is

```
<a class="portfolio-item" style="background-image: url(img/portfolio8.jpg);" href="">
```

I am trying to import portfolio8.jpg that is originaly present in the img folder in static files in django. I changed the code to:

```
<a class="portfolio-item" style="background-image: url({% static 'proj/img/portfolio8.jpg' %});" href="">
```

Doing this didnt work. It will be great if someone could help on how to load the img url from the style.

Comment: Is the image located inside the static folder?

Comment: Did you set static files directory in settings?

Comment: Yes, the static files are working for all other cases. Like, I tried to load image from href by loading from static. So, I added {% load static %} and in the href, I added {% static 'proj/img/logo.png' %}, and it works perfectly fine. It is just not working in the case when I am adding it in the style area

Comment: If you are adding it in css for background-image, call it directly with complete path e.g.`static/rest_of_path`, instead of writing inside static tag.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load static files, first you may have to collect the static files with this command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

And in the template, loading the static tag with:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass image in the style tag. What that does is, it will set a background image for a text that is entered(which you are not passing). Try the below code, it should work for you.

```
<a class="portfolio-item" href="">
<img src="{% static 'proj/img/portfolio8.jpg' %}"/>
</a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in style area, try this

`<a class="portfolio-item" style="background-image: url('static/proj/img/portfolio8.jpg');" href="">`